# How to block long running Java program inside Intellij

Tags: java, performance, intellij-idea, infinite-loop

I miss thought about the stop condition of a loop, and therefore the program didn't stop raising CPU to its limits.

The whole Intellij process hangs and become totally unresponsive, knowing that my machine disposes i7 and I am running on Ubuntu which is normally multitasking as any modern OS. I imagine a solution like pausing a program if it continues executing without a change of state, after a time threshold or just when the memory state stagnates (many ideas can be thought).

Is there an established programming solution to stay safe from one of these situations (when testing, I am aware that an infinite program can be useful) but in case infinitely doing basic CPU operation, it is not.

Does running inside a differed thread help CPU charge dispatching resources ?

Is there a way in Intellij to stay safe from such a situation.

```
        int rect_a = 100;
        int rect_b = 50;

        for (int j=1; j<rect_a; j++) {
            for (int i=0; i<j; i++) {
                //some computation
                j = method() that returns 0 alwayse. (bad logic)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show the code that is producing such problems.

Comment: You might want to include the relevant portion of the code which is hanging.  The fix here may not have anything to do with IntelliJ.

Comment: it isn't really have to do with my code, in my case, I just have been setting `j` back to zero inside the loop accidently

Comment: so that code will loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

As your code is reset `j` to `zero` then the code will never end

consider

```
int rect_a = 100;

for (int j=1; j<rect_a; j++) {
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++) {
        j = 0;
    }
}

System.out.println("ended");
```

`ended` is never printed.  The computer is only doing what you tell it to

Comment: yes Scary Wombat, but I gently rewind my question, my concern is not my program itself, how to safely run in development stage, a piece of code, in case it does't cease while the same state of variables is maintained.

Comment: How would the IDE know whether this is intentional or a bug?

Comment: RIP recursion :0 It's not a bug, it's a feature :) A possible solution is not to change the `j` within the "`for` cycle" once you have already defined it progression... Use another variable instead and implement another exit rule either in the first `for` declaration or within the block itself.